# Angular 2 Update Select by Changing Model in Unit Test

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a `select` element in my template as follows:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="snapshotCriteria.salesArea" required>
  <option *ngFor="let salesArea of salesAreas" [ngValue]="salesArea">
    {{salesArea.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

You can see that the model is bound to `snapshotCriteria.salesArea` which is an object so we use `ngValue` instead of `value`. The `salesArea` property itself is also an object.

---

The component is as follows:

```
export class Component implements OnInit {

  salesAreas: SalesArea[];

  snapshotCriteria: SnapshotCriteria = {
    salesArea: null,
    date: null,
    startTime: 600,
    endTime: 3059
  };


  constructor(private salesAreaService: SalesAreaService) {}


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.salesAreaService.fetchSalesAreas(salesAreas) => this.salesAreas = salesAreas);
  }

}
```

Note that `salesArea` which is bound to the `select` model is initialised to `null`.

---

The template functions correctly when changes are made via the template by manipulating the dropdown. However in my unit tests, I directly update the model which the `select` element references and contrary to what I'd expect, the view is not updated! As the field is required, my test is unable to submit the form as validation fails. This is the test:

```
it('...', fakeAsync(() => {

  spyOn(salesAreaService, 'fetchSalesAreas').and.returnValue(Observable.of([
    {areaNumber: 1, name: 'A'} as any as SalesArea,
    {areaNumber: 2, name: 'B'} as any as SalesArea,
    {areaNumber: 3, name: 'C'} as any as SalesArea
  ]));

  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();

  component.snapshotCriteria = {
    salesArea: {areaNumber: 1, name: 'A'} as SalesArea,
    date: new Date(2015, 5, 25),
    startTime: 1000,
    endTime: 1001
  } as SnapshotCriteria;

  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();

}));
```

Debugging shows that the `select` element is not updated. I have tried various things to no avail:

1. Not re-instantiating the object in the test.
2. Instantiating the `salesArea` object to an empty object instead of
   `null`.
3. Dispatching `input` and `change` events in the test.
4. Listening to `ngModelChange` in the view but this is not triggered
   in the test.

A note of interest is that by using `value` over `ngValue` in the template, I am able to update the view by changing the underlying model.

Comment: This behaviour is similar to what I experienced when testing a directive with a `select` element. I had to make multiple `detectChanges` and `whenStable` (I wasn't using `fakeAsync`) calls. Try making another call to `fixture.detectChanges(); tick();`. (I did raise an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11895) for this, but, in retrospect, my repro wasn't test-based and focused on some other odd behaviour I'd found when investigating things. I might raise another, more test-focused issue.)

Comment: @cartant The fixture is stable at all times during the test, adding more calls to `tick()` has no effect.

Comment: It's the multiple `detectChanges` calls that are important. That's what solved it for me. However, as I was not using `fakeAsync`, mine were paired with `whenStable` calls.

Comment: @cartant Adding multiple `detectChanges` and `tick` calls has no effect.

Comment: Can you add `salesAreas` array? I assume you have to set current value something like `salesArea: salesAreas[0]` or `salesArea: salesAreas.find(x => x.areaNumber === 1)`

Comment: @yurzui The initial selection should be empty.

Comment: I talk about your test.

Comment: @yurzui I've added more information regarding the test and the component.

Comment: See my example https://plnkr.co/edit/L6Zwl7WEefmrinqoyAaj?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for the plunkr, I'm taking a look now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need to do as follows:

```
it('...', fakeAsync(() => {
  var mockArr = [
    {areaNumber: 1, name: 'A'} as any as SalesArea,
    {areaNumber: 2, name: 'B'} as any as SalesArea,
    {areaNumber: 3, name: 'C'} as any as SalesArea
  ];
  spyOn(salesAreaService, 'fetchSalesAreas').and.returnValue(Observable.of(mockArr));

  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();

  component.snapshotCriteria = {
    salesArea: mockArr.find(x => x.areaNumber === 1),
    date: new Date(2015, 5, 25),
    startTime: 1000,
    endTime: 1001
  } as SnapshotCriteria;

  fixture.detectChanges();

  tick();
  expect(...);
}));
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/L6Zwl7WEefmrinqoyAaj?p=preview)**

Comment: 100% right, thank you! It appears that the value of `component.snapshotCriteria.salesArea` needs to be an object with reference to the `salesAreas` passed into the `ngFor` of the `option` element.